# Create a datetime64[ns] variable (or use between_time function?)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I have a dataframe with a time column. First df.dtypes return ‘object’ and the values all look like this:

```
2019-10-18T08:13:26.702000
```

I use pd.to_datetime and df.dtypes return ‘datetime64[ns]’ and the values all look like this:

```
2019-10-18 08:13:26.702000
```

I want to able to pick out a range of the dateframe, based on a time interval. I first tried:

```
df.iloc[pd.DatetimeIndex['ts'].indexer_between_time(datetime.time(2019,10,18,8,19,0),
                                                    datetime.time(2019,10,18,8,21,0))]
```

I then get TypeError:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-9e1f5757369e> in <module>
----> 1 df.iloc[pd.DatetimeIndex['ts'].indexer_between_time(datetime.time(2019,10,18,8,19,0),
      2                                                     datetime.time(2019,10,18,8,21,0))]
      3 
      4 
      5 #df.pd.DatetimeIndex['ts'].indexer_between_time(time(8:19), time(08:21:00))

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I then try to work around by defining a datetime64[ns] variable, for then trying to perform a ‘greater than and smaller than’ selection. But I am not able to define a variable without error. (And not really sure if this workaround will work..?)

```
time1 = pd.datetime.datetime64[ns](2019-10-18T08:19:00.0)
```

Gives:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the best way to sort out a time interval of my dataframe? I need to be able to sort on seconds, not ms.

If needed, this is a part of my dateframe after converting to datetime64[ns]:

```
                        ts  value
0  2019-10-18 08:13:26.702     14
1  2019-10-18 08:13:26.765     10
2  2019-10-18 08:13:26.790      5
3  2019-10-18 08:13:26.889      6
4  2019-10-18 08:13:26.901      8
5  2019-10-18 08:13:27.083     33
6  2019-10-18 08:13:27.098     21
7  2019-10-18 08:13:27.101     11
8  2019-10-18 08:13:27.129     22
9  2019-10-18 08:13:27.159     29
10 2019-10-18 08:13:27.188      7
11 2019-10-18 08:13:27.212     20
12 2019-10-18 08:13:27.228     24
13 2019-10-18 08:13:27.246     30
14 2019-10-18 08:13:27.395     34
15 2019-10-18 08:23:26.375     40
16 2019-10-18 08:23:26.527     49
17 2019-10-18 08:23:26.725     48
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `DatetimeIndex` from column `ts`, one possible solution is use `DatetimeIndex` or convert column to index and select `.index`:

```
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
df = df.iloc[pd.DatetimeIndex(df['ts']).indexer_between_time(datetime.time(8,20,0),
                                                             datetime.time(8,27,0))]
```

---

```
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
df = df.iloc[df.set_index('ts').index.indexer_between_time(datetime.time(8,20,0),
                                                           datetime.time(8,27,0))]

print (df)
                        ts  value
15 2019-10-18 08:23:26.375     40
16 2019-10-18 08:23:26.527     49
17 2019-10-18 08:23:26.725     48
```

But simplier solution is if use `DatetimeIndex` - convert column `ts` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then use [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])
df = df.set_index('ts').between_time(datetime.time(8,20,0), datetime.time(8,27,0))
print (df)
                         value
ts                            
2019-10-18 08:23:26.375     40
2019-10-18 08:23:26.527     49
2019-10-18 08:23:26.725     48
```